# Windows Phone 8 Emulator returning Redmond location only

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am using the following code

```
Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator
{
    DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High
};
Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
```

while running the simulator each time i get the location as Redmond, is this a bug, if yes then how can we get rid out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is location sensor simulator available for Windows Phone emulator (both 7.5 and 8): [How to test apps that use location data for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202933%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

It looks like that:

[image: Windows Phone Emulator location simulator]

You can set current phone location to anything you want using that tool. IT also allows you to record paths and playing recorded paths.

To open it click *Additional Tools* button - the last one within emulator toolbar. It's hovered to yellow on photo below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked but cant i have anything on load of application itself?