# I cannot get the current location in windows phone 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I am trying to get the current location with the help of map control in windows phone applications. I also added service token and location is enabled.

```
Geolocator gl = new Geolocator();
gl.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
var pos = await gl.GetGeopositionAsync();
await mymap.TrySetViewAsync(pos.Coordinate.Point, 16);
```

But when I try to execute the code it shows the different location. Currently am in India but it is showing in USA

[image]

Comment: Is this runing on the emulator? If so, have you actually set the location via the `>` button?

Comment: If you're using a real device, does it have a clear view of the sky, and where does the Maps app think it is?

Comment: So, have you set the location for the emulator usign the Location tab - because that is the location it will return (the default being one of the Microsoft campuses, if memory serves correctly)

Comment: How to set the location. Please help me

Comment: Look at the accepted answer on [Windows Phone 8 Emulator returning Redmond location only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15789998/50447)

Comment: Thanks for your help, also please solve one more issue. Go through the below link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162750/get-nearby-fuel-stations-using-bing-maps-api)